# Android Emulator cannot connect to webcam with "unrecognized pixel format error"

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

After upgrading my macbook to Yosemite, I have been getting the following error whenever I launch an android emulator.  I've tried all combinations of settings, but all report the same error. Any attempt to launch the built in camera app, or use the camera in my own app produces a crash.  Below is the error I get when the emulator launches.  Running the emulator with additional debug flags did not produce any additional useful info.

```
emulator: ERROR: Unrecognized pixel format 'v024'
emulator: ERROR: Pixel format 'v024' reported by the camera device is unsupported
```

This is an example of one of my emulator configurations:

```
Name: Nexus_5_API_21
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64)
Path: /Users/rob/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21.avd
Target: Google APIs (API level 21)
Skin: nexus_5
SD Card: 100M
Snapshot: no
hw.lcd.density: 480
hw.dPad: no
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.camera.back: webcam0
disk.dataPartition.size: 200M
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
runtime.network.latency: none
skin.dynamic: no
hw.keyboard: yes
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.device.hash2: MD5:2fa0e16c8cceb7d385183284107c0c88
hw.ramSize: 1536
tag.id: google_apis
tag.display: Google APIs
hw.sdCard: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.mainKeys: no
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.trackBall: no
hw.device.name: Nexus 5
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
hw.battery: yes
AvdId: Nexus_5_API_21
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
hw.audioInput: yes
hw.camera.front: none
hw.gps: yes
avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5 API 21
snapshot.present: no
vm.heapSize: 64
runtime.scalefactor: auto
```

The webcam works fine for other applications like photobooth or facetime.

Any ideas for how I might be able to resolve this error are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Experiencing same problem here :/.

Comment: Might be worth filing a bug on http://b.android.com/.

Comment: @AlbertoRico -- Glad to hear I'm not the only one.

Comment: @fadden -- Agreed, though I'd check here first.  Bug report is filed:  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=95299&thanks=95299&ts=1420911291

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same error. I fixed it by opening the Photo Booth app and then restarted the AVD while having Photo Booth in the background.

Comment: Nice find!  Worked for me as well.  Once I used the workaround, subsequent launches of AVD worked without requiring Photobooth running in the background.

Sadly, any form of reboot, would undo whatever it is that phototbooth "fixed" and required me touse the workaround again.

Comment: Weird bug, but your answer works!,
Please also note that in order to work, you need to set only one camera to Webcam0, not both, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Crazy that opening photo booth helps the issue - but it works.

Comment: Where is the Photo Booth in AVD?

Comment: The Photo Booth is an OSX Application that has nothing to do with the AVD. Search for Photo Booth and you shall find it.

Comment: Perhaps StackOverflow should have a "accepted workaround" option.  Until then I'm flagging this as the accepted answer as it appears to be a recurring theme for many readers, and this workaround appears to be universal.  Thanks again @AndersLarsen.

Comment: June 29, 2017, this workaround is still needed for me.